# Get HTML page from Origin with Webclient and C#

Tags: c#

I tried to get HTML (fully rendered) from [origin](https://www.origin.com/irl/en-us/store) page with WebClient and C#.

I installed phantomJs but that doesn't give me the fully rendered page, I used the example from [here](https://gist.github.com/DotNetNerd/5635371). Of course, I changed the URL

```
string output = grabby.Grab("https://www.origin.com/irl/en-us/store");
```

How can I achieve this ?